# Regex Pattern with Unicode doesn't do case folding

Tags: java, regex, internationalization, case-folding

In C# it appears that `Grüsse` and `Grüße` are considered equal in most circumstances as is explained by [this](http://esmithy.net/2007/10/15/why-stringcomparisonordinal-is-usually-the-right-choice/) nice webpage. I'm trying to find a similar behavior in Java - obviously not in `java.lang.String`.

I thought I was in luck with `java.regex.Pattern` in combination with `Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`. The Javadoc says:

> UNICODE_CASE enables Unicode-aware case folding. When this flag is specified then
>   case-insensitive matching, when enabled by the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag,
>   is done in a manner consistent with the Unicode Standard.

Yet the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("Grüsse"), 
                     Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(p.matcher("Grüße").matches());
```

yields `false`. Why? And is there an alternative way of reproducing the C# case folding behavior?

---- edit ----

As @VGR pointed out, `String.toUpperCase` will convert `ß` to `ss`, which may or may not be case folding (maybe I'm confusing concepts here). However other characters in the German locale are not "folded", for instance `ü` does not become `UE`. So to make my initial example more complete, is there a way to make `Grüße` and `Gruesse` compare equal in Java?

I was thinking the `java.text.Normalizer` class could be used to do just that, but it converts `ü` to `u?` rather than `ue`. It also hasn't an option to provide a `Locale`, which confuses me even more.

Comment: why: the javadoc also says: "This class is in conformance with Level 1 of [Unicode Technical Standard #18: Unicode Regular Expression](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/), plus RL2.1 Canonical Equivalents." - and the linked doc states "at Level 1 only simple case matches are necessary" - probably will not work with the actual java SE implementation...

Comment: I’m pretty sure `s1.toUpperCase().equals(s2.toUpperCase())` will work.  equalsIgnoreCase will not work, because, as its documentation says, it performs case conversions one character at a time, so only one-to-one character mappings are applied.

Comment: Thanks both for your insightful comments. @VGR you're right, this works. But I've thrown in another question - please see edit.

Comment: `"SS"` equals `"ß".toUppercase(Locale.GERMAN)"` but this does not hold for `"ss".equals("ß")`.

Comment: A [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with its strength set to [PRIMARY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#PRIMARY) will accomplish your original goal.  But I’m not sure if it can be made to equate “Grüße” and “Gruesse”.

Comment: Why is it that case is so difficult to get right in Regular Expressions? Sometimes when using find and replace tools based on Regular Expressions, things like case really matter a great deal, so why standard Regex evaluation engines have not yet been able to universally deal with this issue perfectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the following facts:

- `Character.toUpperCase()` cannot do case folding, as one character
  must map to one character.
- `String.toUpperCase()` will do case folding.
- `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` uses `Character.toUpperCase()`
  internally, so doesn't do case folding.

Conclusion (as @VGR pointed out): if you need case insensitive matching with case folding, you need to do:

`foo.toUpperCase().equals(bar.toUpperCase())`

and not:

`foo.equalsIgnoreCase(bar)`

As for the `ü` and `ue` equality, I've managed to do it with a `RuleBasedCollator` and my own rules (one would expect `Locale.German` had that built-in but alas). It looked really silly/over-engineered, and since I needed only the equality, not the sorting/collating, in the end I've settled for a simple set of `String.replace` prior to comparison. It sucks but it works and is transparent/readable.

Comment: Note that Unicode distinguishes between *simple* case folding (where 1 character is replaced by 1 other) and *full* case folding. *Full* case folding is required to turn `ß` into `ss`. For all the mappings, see [CaseFolding.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt) in Unicode.

Comment: This is not true in general. For example, it will not work for comparing "ﬂüßchen" to "FLÜSSCHEN", or under regex using either of these patterns: ".*(ß).*", ".*(ss).*"

Answer (score 1):

Use the ICU4J regular expressions, not the JDK ones:
  http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Case-Insensitive-Matching

Answer (score 1):

With the currently accepted answer:

```
foo.toUpperCase().equals(bar.toUpperCase())
```

The following inputs do *not* compare equal even though they should: `Grüsse` and `GRÜẞE`; or `Grüße` and `GRÜẞE`.

Why is that? Let's look at the uppercased strings:

```
"Grüsse".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)  -> "GRÜSSE"
"Grüße".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)   -> "GRÜSSE"
"GRÜẞE".toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)   -> "GRÜẞE"
```

As you can see, the uppercase "sharp S" (`ẞ`) stays that way. To handle that correctly, do this:

```
foo.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT).equals(
    bar.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
```

Note that the order is important. If you uppercase first and then lowercase, it would turn `ẞ` into `ß` (lowercase sharp S) only.